# Testing attribute methods with RSpec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ancestry

Recently I have migrated one of my models from a self made (parent_id based) tree structure to the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) and I have a failing controller spec for the `new` action. The line in question is:

`assigns(:category).should be_a_new(Category).with(parent_id: root_category.id)`

However it complains that there's no attribute `parent_id` and indeed it isn't as parent_id is now a method. How should I modify the above line to check for both a new category and that `category.parent_id == root_category.id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 'parent_id' you can use the column name ancestry uses to store the parent's id which is 'ancestry' by default. You can change the name by setting it as option to the `has_ancestry` class method, e.g. `has_ancestry(ancestry_column: :parent_id)`.

Your modified test code would look as follows:

```
assigns(:category).should be_a_new(Category).with(ancestry: root_category.id.to_s)
```

Comment: However I have noticed that for subsubcategories the ancestry column looks something like: "6/8"... The preferred method would be to test a method's return value, if that's possible.

Comment: Thats true, but RSpec::Rails::Matchers::BeANew#with works only with attributes indeed. I think you have to split the statement into 2 lines `assigns(:category).should be_a_new(Category)` and `assigns(:category).parent_id.should eq root_category.id` or you write your own custom matcher working with methods.

Comment: Bingo! I was looking for that second line and I will look into writing custom matchers also. Thanks!